# Drive API for Android: App folder not getting sync

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying using the [Google API for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) to **create** a file, **search**, **download** and **delete** in the **app folder**.

But i'm getting some problems...
If i use the '**getRootFolder()**' to save my file everything works. But, if i use '**getAppFolder()**' nothing works.

Example:

1. The user download my app, my app search if exist any created file.
2. If nothing return the app create a new file in AppFolder.
3. If the user uninstall the app and download again, the app can't reach the file.

I try '**requestSync**' but nothing happens. I trying using the **Listening for Changes** and **Receiving completion Events**, they return 'Success' but still not sync the AppFolder.

I saw some similar problems, but none works for me.

If i use the 'getRootFolder()' everything works great...

Can you guys help?

Here some Code Examples:

**OnConnected:**

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("automaticBackup", true)) {
        String FILE_PATH = this.getDatabasePath(DataHelper.DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(FILE_PATH);
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        file = new File(FILE_PATH);

        if (hasInternetAccess()) {
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstUse", true)) {
                Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query).setResultCallback(restoreCallBack);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("firstUse", false);
                editor.apply();
            } else {
                // delete existing backup
                Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query).setResultCallback(checkIfFileExists);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here i check if file exist, true delete, false create a new one:**

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> checkIfFileExists = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {

    private DriveId fileId;

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while checking if file exists...");
            return;
        }

        MetadataBuffer metadata = result.getMetadataBuffer();
        if (metadata.getCount() > 0) {
            fileId = metadata.get(0).getDriveId();
            if (fileId != null) {
                Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), fileId.getResourceId()).setResultCallback(deleteFile);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No backup file found");
            // create new contents resource
            Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(createBackupCallBack);
        }
    }
};
```

**Here the code to delete:**

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> deleteFile = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveIdResult driveIdResult) {
        final DriveId driveId = driveIdResult.getDriveId();

        try {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    DriveId fileId = DriveId.decodeFromString(driveId.encodeToString());
                    DriveFile driveFile = fileId.asDriveFile();
                    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status deleteStatus = driveFile.delete(getGoogleApiClient()).await();
                    if (!deleteStatus.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to delete the old backup");
                        return null;
                    }
                    sharedPreferences.edit().remove(driveId.toString()).apply();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Removed old backup.");
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    // create new contents resource
                    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(createBackupCallBack);
                }
            }.execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

**Upload the file to Drive:**

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> createBackupCallBack = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
                    return;
                }
                final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead;
                        try {
                            BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                            inputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }

                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle(DataHelper.DATABASE_NAME)
                                .setMimeType(type)
                                .setStarred(true).build();

                        Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                                .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        };
```

**Result Call Back from upload:**

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> restoreCallBack = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {

    DriveId driveId;

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while restoring...");
        }

        MetadataBuffer metadata = result.getMetadataBuffer();
        if (metadata.getCount() > 0) {
            File fileBD = getDatabasePath(DataHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
            boolean deleted = fileBD.delete();
            Log.d("DELETED", deleted + "");
            driveId = metadata.get(0).getDriveId();
            Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), driveId.getResourceId()).setResultCallback(idCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No backup file found!");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible that the user uninstalls the app before the files are successfully uploaded to the server?
When the user uninstalls the app the files get deleted from the device.

You can use completion events to verify that the files are uploaded to the server.

Comment: Already use the ComplemetionEvent and he return 'Success' when finish, then i uninstall the app and install again the app can't find the file if they are in AppFolder. If they are in RootFolder is almost instant.

Comment: Maybe check that the app is still authorized after you uninstall (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2523073?hl=en).

Comment: Yes still authorized, cause when he can't find the file i create a new one.

Comment: Maybe you can add some code samples so it's clear what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

It may be permission issue. Adding drive.appfolder authorization scopes to GoogleApiClient may solve your problem. For example:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required to access app folder
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Comment: I Already got what i wanted to do, using the AppFolder, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, you need to sync with the drive before querying the AppFolder.

Use this after connecting to the drive:

```
Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {

    }
});
```